# Learning MIPS: Creating a simple program to read numbers and print them

Tags: mips

I'm struggling with learning MIPS right now, and I'm finding it isn't as easy as C++ was.

Right now, I'm to edit/write a program that will take ten number's from a user, then print those numbers out at the end with commas between them, and no comma after the last number. Example:

```
Enter a number 1
Enter a number 2
Enter a number 9
Enter a number 11
Enter a number 99
Enter a number 12
Enter a number 24
Enter a number 90
Enter a number 17
Enter a number 82
1, 2, 9, 11, 99, 12, 24, 90, 7, 82
```

This is the given code:

```
    .data
    .space 40                 # set aside 40 bytes for 10 integers
prompt:
    .asciiz "Enter a number " # address 0x10010028
comma:
    .asciiz ", "              # address 0x10010038

.globl main
.text
main:
    lui $a0, 0x1001 # get start of data segment
    jal getdata     # call getdata function

    lui $a0, 0x1001 # get start of data segment
    jal print       # call print function

    ori $v0, $0, 10 # set command to exit
    syscall         # end program

getdata:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4    # allocate space on stack
    sw $ra, 0($sp)       # save $ra
    ori $t1, $a0, 0      # address of array

    lui $t1, 0x1001      # start of data
    ori $a0, $a0, 0x0028 # address of prompt
    ori $t0, $0, 10      # counter

top:
    beq $t0, $0, ret     # while not 0

    jal printstr         # call function to print prompt
    ori $v0, $0, 5       # set command to read integer
    syscall              # read int
    sw $v0, 0($t1)       # save int in memory
    addi $t1, $t1, 4     # increment to next location

    addi $t0, $t0, -1    # decrement counter
    j top                # repeat

ret:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)       # restore return address
    addi $sp, $sp, 4     # clean up stack
    jr $ra               # return from call

    # print
    # parameter: $a0 holds address of list in memory
    # purpose: print the list separated by commas
print:
    #to be completed
    jr $ra

    # printstr
    # paramters: $a0 holds address of string to print
    # purpose: print the string parameter
printstr:
    #to be completed
    jr $ra
```

Where I believe I'm struggling at is the "print" portion. I have the
following for printstr: and for getdata:

```
printstr:
    ori $v0, $0, 4  # command to print string at $a0
    syscall
    jr $ra          # return from call

getdata:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4    # allocate space on stack
    sw $ra, 0($sp)       # save $ra
    ori $t1, $a0, 0      # address of array

    lui $t1, 0x1001      # start of data
    ori $a0, $a0, 0x0028 # address of prompt
    ori $t0, $0, 10      # counter
```

And then this is the code I've been trying to use for the loop...

```
print:
    addi $t2, $t2, 10
    addi $t0, $t0, 1      # Enter into the loop by increment 1
    ori $v0, $0, 4        # Print the 1st value and then loop
                          # start from the 2nd value

    syscall

    jal loop # Jump to loop

loop:
    beq $t0, $t2, end  # checks if t2=t0, if it does then ends the program
    lui $t3, 0x1001    # loads the upper limit of t3 to 1001
    or $a0, $0, $t3    # sets the upper limit of a0 to 1001
    ori $v0, $0, 1     # sets v0 to print integer
    syscall            # prints integer
    addi $t3, $t3, 4   # moves t3 to the next address

    ori $a0, $a0, 0x0038  # sets a0 to the address of comma
    ori $v0, $0, 4        # Print string at $a0
    syscall
    addi $t0, $t0, 1      # increases the value at t0 by 1
    jr $ra
```

However, when I run the program it spits out "268500992, ,". So I'm not getting my input numbers or the correct number of commas even. I know that means that my loop isn't running all the way through. I'm not supposed to use and pseudo code, and only what I've learned so far - so array's are out of the question.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm missing? Does it have something to do with the stack values (which I don't completely understand)?

Comment: Are you allowed to call functions in the C library?  This task will be _much_ easier with access to `fgets` and `printf`.

Comment: I am not. Since it's an introductory class, I have to learn to do it the long way first. =\

Comment: Hmph. I think that's ass-backward, but never mind. Can you give us a link to the programmer's reference for the environment you are using? In order to help you, we are going to need to understand _exactly_ what the system calls do, and they do not appear to correspond to Unix `read` and `write`.

Comment: We're using the MARS simulator created by Missouri State. 

http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/

And then the MIPS "Green Sheet". It doesn't show the $v0 values on the green sheet, but I believe they're the standard when $v0 is 1, it prints the integer in $a0 kind of deal.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no standard for what system call numbers mean, nor for where the arguments to a system call go. And that's the most important thing we need to know.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're talking about then. If you're talking about the syscall's in the program, they are part of the $v0. This is the syscall information for the MARS simulator we're using. https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html      But we are only using the first 10.

Comment: Aha, that help page is exactly what I wanted.  Thanks.

Comment: Why is the first integer printed with system call 4 instead of system call 1? And where in `loop` are you setting `$a0` to the value to print with system call 1?

Comment: Michael - it's because it generates the prompt to "Enter a number" so it's setting $a0 to value 4, which prints a string.

Comment: Incidentally, forget what I said about the C library; the "system calls" you're working with are high-level enough that this wouldn't be any easier with the C library.

Comment: But the comment for for `print` says `purpose: print the list separated by commas`, so why would it print the `"Enter a number"` prompt? Also, `$a0=4` doesn't mean `print_string` - `$v0=4` does.

Comment: I was thinking that because it was before the loop taking the numbers... But what you're saying makes more sense. The code for printinstr would be generating the "Enter a prompt" and then going forward. So that line of code in print is unnecessary... Especially since I just rewrite $v0 to 1 in the loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think your code for `printstr` is correct, and `getdata` also looks fine (a little odd, but you didn't write that, yes?) The bugs are all in `print`.  I'm not going to spell it out for you, because this is homework, but the structure of the loop in `print` should be very similar to the structure of the loop in `getdata`:

```
    # on entry, $a0 = address of integer array
print:
    ori $t0, $0, 10      # counter
    ori $t1, $a0, 0      # t1 points to current array element

print_loop:
    ### if this isn't the first iteration, print ", "
    ### load value at $t1 into $a0
    ### print the integer in $a0

    addi $t1, $t1, 4     # advance to next array element
    addi $t0, $t0, -1    # decrement counter
    bne  $t0, $0, print_loop

    ### print a carriage return

    jr $ra               # return from call
```

Each thing prefixed by `###` is a placeholder for code you need to write.

Comment: I sadly don't have my program in front of me, so I can't test it as I go... But wouldn't I use                bne $t0, $0, comma        ori $a0, $0, $t0               $v0, $0, 1      syscall                       and then I don't know what a carriage return is? =s

Comment: ori $v0, $0, 1  ... . Not just $v0 by itself. Thinking about it, for the first iteration, I would use bne $t0, 10, comma     because if $t0 is 10, I don't want a comma initially. Then I set $a0 to the value stored in $t1 (so I knew which value from my input was to be printed), print the integer with a syscall...

Comment: zwol - What does "Print a Carriage Return" mean to do?

Comment: ...I don't know how to answer that. There are several other names for a carriage return - newline, end of line, linefeed - but if "carriage return" doesn't mean anything to you, I doubt the others will...